# Can't execute my SQL Server stored procedure using db.Database.SqlQuery(sql)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to execute a SQL Server stored procedure from my C# code. Here's the code I am using:

```
var sql = @"test";   

try
{
    var query = db.Database.SqlQuery(sql);
    return Ok();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return BadRequest(ex.Message);
}
```

Here's the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    PRINT 'INSERT 1 START';
    INSERT INTO Message (Text, TypeId) VALUES ('Message 5', 0);
    THROW 50002,'thrown',1;
    PRINT 'INSERT 2 START';
    INSERT INTO Message (Text, TypeId) VALUES ('Message 6', 0);
    PRINT 'GOT HERE';
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    RETURN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
END CATCH

END
```

I am getting a message that says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'Database.SqlQuery(string, params object[])' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   WebRole C:\H\server\WebRole\Controllers\Web API -
>   Data\MessageController.cs 28  Active

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here.  Also this is just a test for me but I would like to be able to have the transaction commit or rollback. Is there something that I need to do on the C# side to make this possible?

Comment: Same message with dbo.test.  The message is referring to parameters of SqlQuery

Comment: I'm not even getting to that point. The program will not compile so I know it's nothing to do with whatever I have set sql too.

Comment: Have you tried passing in null as the SqlParameter array it is asking for?

Comment: This also gives an error. It will not accept <null>

Comment: @Alan, see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `ExecuteSqlCommand` method, like below:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec dbo.test");
```